# ActiveMQ message payload limit

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I failed to found out the limit of the payload for the single message in ActiveMQ queue. The problem is that I have to pass a big message via ActiveMQ queue. I have an intention of passing a message that contains from 1 kb to 10 mb of data. 
I know that there is a opportunity of passing the reference to the object in File System in the message body, but I want to avoid it, so I want to know the limit of the message.

Thanks.

Comment: Personally I would rather push small notification and force client to download message content via eg. REST